# JFlex regex vs keywords in lexical rules

Tags: java, regex, lexical, jflex

What's the point in allowing the use of both keywords and regexes in the section covering lexical rules in a JFlex input file?

It seems

```
retrieve { action code}
```

...and

```
 "retrieve" { action code }
```

... both match an input containing "retrieve", the first one being a regex and the second one being a keyword. I mean all keywords should be able to be interpreted in the form of a regex so it seems superfluous to allow both.

Comment: There are no keywords in lex/flex/jflex. Everything is done via regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure quite what you mean by "keyword". According to [the "Lexical rules" section of the *JFlex User's Manual*](http://jflex.de/manual.html#LexRules), *both* of your examples use regexes.

It's true that the regexes `retrieve` and `"retrieve"` are equivalent, but that's just because the sole effect of the `"..."` notation is to disable regex metacharacters, and none of the characters in `retrieve` are regex metacharacters to begin with. (By the way, you can also wrap just *part* of a regex in quotation marks; so, for example, `retrieve` is also equivalent to `r"et"ri"ev"e`.)

The quotation marks are more useful if (say) one of the keywords in your language is `+++***+++`, in which case you could write either of these:

```
\+\+\+\*\*\*\+\+\+ { action code }
"+++***+++" { action code }
```

Comment: Aha... Then i misunderstood things.. Is using "...." to escape metacharacters a convention used in regexes generally or just in this specific situation? I thought that " wasn't considered a character with special meaning in regexes and would therefore match an actual ". (So "retrieve" would match only "retrieve" and not retrieve as a regex, therefore i draw the conclusion that it wasn't a regex)

Comment: @fast-reflexes: "Regexes" isn't really a single unitary concept; there's a lot of variation between regex engines. So saying that `"` isn't special in regexes is a bit like saying that `floobet` isn't a reserved word in programming languages: generally true, but not necessarily categorical. (But to be sure, I've never seen *any* other regex language that uses `"` in this way.)